# How do I bring the quartile values on a box whisker plot to an ordinal scale to be used as the dependent variable in ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, boxplot, ordinal

My dependent variable is otter encounter rate, which I plotted in box whisker plot. My professor suggested me to convert that to ordinal values to be used in ordinal regression along with habitat parameters as independent variables. I am doing all the analyses in R. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are after?

```
df <- tibble(num = 1:10)


df %>% 
  mutate(num_ordinal = case_when(
    num > 7 ~ "high",
    num <= 7 & num > 5 ~ "med",
    num <= 5 ~ "small"
    ) %>% as.factor()
  )
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
     num num_ordinal
   <int> <fct>      
 1     1 small      
 2     2 small      
 3     3 small      
 4     4 small      
 5     5 small      
 6     6 med        
 7     7 med        
 8     8 high       
 9     9 high       
10    10 high
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert quartile values as an ordinal variable, you need to convert the values as factors with factor levels in sequential order.

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse) # to use the functions below

df <- data.frame(
  otter_encounter = 1:100, # original dependent variable
  habitat_1 = rnorm(100), # independent variable 1
  habitat_2 = rnorm(100) # independent variable 2
) %>% 
  mutate(encounter_quartile = factor(ntile(otter_encounter, 4), levels = 1:4)) # your ordinal quartile values
```

`ntile()` is a function that can create quartiles. If you already have a "quartile" column in your data frame, you can replace the ntile(...) code with your quartile column name. 
Name the four quartile values in rank order for the `levels` of `factor()`.

You can run ordinal logistic regression starting with `polr()`:

```
library(MASS)

m <- polr(encounter_quartile ~ habitat_1 + habitat_2, data = df, Hess=TRUE) 
summary(m)
```

where `m` is your regression formula.

You will need more to complete the analysis, but that's not your question so I will leave that out. 
For a R tutorial on ordinal logistic regression, see https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/.